# Using SLF4J from within the build

Tags: sbt, slf4j

My build runs Grunt for js/css minification, using [a library](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/tree/master/frontend-plugin-core). I made a basic sbt wrapper around it by defining a grunt task, so when I run "grunt" in the sbt console it runs grunt through Node.js on my project's resources.

The library I'm using is logging through SLF4J. (Using SLF4J's ClassLoader lookup mechanism.)
How can I provide an SLF4J logger for it, so that it logs output to the sbt console?

One thing I've already tried is writing a simple implementation of StaticLoggerBinder from SLF4J, and putting it in `.my_project/project/src/main/scala/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.scala`.
However, the class loader (sbt's or slf4j's) cannot find it in the classpath...

Comment: You should be use sbt's logging APIs if you're inside of sbt.  This way task output will work with the `last` task.  See: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Howto/logging.html#log for an example.  You should be able to directly pipe grunt process to an sbt logger using the Process API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that the library I use, by design, logs via SLF4J (so it can be used from multiple build tools - Maven for example provides its own logger implementation, different from sbt's implementation, but there's a brigde between Maven's log and SLF4J that makes that very easy. Gradle uses SLF4J directly as far as I know.) I'm not sure if the same exists for sbt?

Comment: I don't think it does.  However, that (a bridge) sounds like a useful sbt plugin, if you'd like to contribute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There we go, I fixed it. I wrote a library for it. :-)
You include the library in your setup, bootstrap SLF4J and off you go!

https://github.com/eirslett/sbt-slf4j